# EUnit output debug info from tested modules

Tags: erlang, eunit, dbg

Let us say I have a module called `example.erl`

In this module I use the following construct for debugging:

```
%%% Switch debugging output on/off:
%-define(DBG(Str, Args), ok).
-define(DBG(Str, Args), io:format(Str, Args)).
```

It helps me to output various debugging info into the Erlang shell:

```
?DBG("Function fun1 starting... ~n", [])
```

But if I call `example.erl` from `example_tests` with `example:test()`, this output info does not appear.

How can I make it visible during a EUnit test?

UPD: I have found [some related info](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html#Debugging_macros), but I still do not know how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As describe in the page you mention, you can use debugMsg or debugFmt.

```
?debugMsg("Function fun1 starting...")
```

or

```
?debugFmt("Function fun1 starting...", [])
```

Make sure you have include eunit's header file in your module file.

```
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").
```

If you want to disable debug macros for example in staging, define NODEBUG in compiling modules.

Comment: ?debugFmt works fine! But how can I switch it on/off quickly? I used to use ?DBG defined in two lines (as in my question). I have tried to do the following: `-define(dbgFmt(Str,Args), ok).`, but the output is still there.

Comment: define NODEBUG macro such as `-define(NODEBUG, true).`. Make sure you define it **BEFORE** including eunit.hrl,

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem. Found another way thanks to @rvirding. The solution is to write to the *user* output stream (as in `io:format(user, "~w", [Term])`).

This is documented in the section titled "EUnit captures standard output" of the [eunit docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html).

My "trace.hrl" file is shown below:

```
%% If compiled with {d, TEST, true}
%% This happens automatically during `rebar3 eunit`
-ifdef(TEST).
-define(TRACE(Template, Args), io:format(user, "TRACE ~p:~p ~p~n", [?MODULE, ?LINE, lists:flatten(Args)])).
-else.
-define(TRACE(_T, _A), void).
-endif.
```

A sample source file:

```
-module(foo).
-export([ api/1 ]).

-include("trace.hrl").

api(Arg) ->
    ?TRACE("Called with Arg ~p~n", [Arg]),
    ok.
```

I prefer this method to `?debugFmt`, as the latter injects EUnit specific code into your *source* (rather than *test*) code.